# Selenium PageFactory initialization best practice

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

In Page Object Design pattern, I have learned that any action performed on a page that takes you to another page must return an object of the latter's type. Such as the example below. Clicking register from the MainPage will take you to the RegisterPage.

```
public class MainPage {
    ...

    public RegisterPage clickRegister() {
        registerButton.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, RegisterPage.class);
    }
}
```

Example of how the clickRegister is invoked in a Selenium test script:

```
RegisterPage registerpage = MainPage.clickRegister();
```

My question is, does it still make sense for the RegisterPage's constructor to have the PageFactory.initElements() like below? Even though it has already been initialized once from the clickRegister() method's return.

```
public class RegisterPage {
    public RegisterPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, you can just `return new RegisterPage(driver);`, and everything will be fine.

Comment: I would prefer to use the PageFactory so that I can make use of annotations such as FindBy to auto-map WebElements whenever the initElements is called.

Comment: As you said, you are already using `PageFactory.initElements(...)` in your RegisterPage constructor, therefore you are able to use `return new RegisterPage(driver);` from the calling class and your Page Factory will still work as you expect. I do this all the time!

Comment: I get it now. You are right. I first understood it as removingthe PageFactory from both the calling and callee class. Thank you